# SharePoint Online - How to move sites with considerable data between site collections

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I have a requirement to move sub-sites from one site collection to another on SharePoint online. The sub-sites have considerable amount (~1GB) of data in them. Therefore exporting and importing would not be an option.

I would also like to retain permissions, but if the permissions are lost then I am not worried. I will apply them again.

It would be really nice if anybody can point me towards the right direction.

Cheers,
Sabrish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sabrish, I would probably tell you to buy a 3rd party tool especially if you're going to do this on anything resembling a regular basis.  Something like **Sharegate** (http://en.share-gate.com/) would do the trick and it's not very expensive.

You could also download a "free lite" version of **Metalogix Content Matrix**.  This should do what you need, but you will be limited to 25GB...you'll have to pay beyond that if you still want to use the tool.  You also have to give them your contact info when you download it, so a salesperson will call you every other day to see how you're doing. :)

https://www.metalogix.com/Promotions/Content-Matrix-Migration-Express-Download.aspx

You could also roll your own solution, either writing some .NET code or a PowerShell script. I personally wouldn't recommend that approach especially in a live/production environment.

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you very much. I was actually looking into these products. Do you know if any of these products provide access to their api's which I can plug into and automate the entire process of migration with the click of button? PS: I am looking at the respective websites to find more information. But cannont find anything regarding API access.

Comment: I know Metalogix can generate PowerShell scripts based on the configured migration. You can then just execute the script.  As far as exposing actual APIs...they are probably some there, whether or not they are "officially" documented is another story.  Google "metalogix content matrix powershell" for info on their PowerShell scripting capabilities.